# Zybooks Python activity 1.10.1

Tags: python

Hello I'm new to scripting, learning in the Zybooks is difficult for me as it explains little. On the challenge 1.10.1 it asks for me to use output commands. The first line has this:

```py
user_num = int(input('Enter integer: /n'))
```

When I try to complete the lab it gives me an error like so:

> Enter integer: /n

If anyone has done this lab successfully please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'/n' has to be replaced with '\n'.
Use the key located in the upside of 'Enter'.

Please try this code. It will works well :)

```py
user_num = int(input('Enter integer: \n'))
```